# lost+found directory in /home

Tags: boot, partitioning, mount, hard-drive

I'm running Ubuntu Server 20.04 LTS. I have 2 drives. 1 M2 and 1 HDD mounted on /home:

```
Filesystem      1K-blocks       Used Available Use% Mounted on
udev              8064404          0   8064404   0% /dev
tmpfs             1622128       1380   1620748   1% /run
/dev/nvme0n1p3  119965456    7088932 106739592   7% /
tmpfs             8110636          0   8110636   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs                5120          0      5120   0% /run/lock
tmpfs             8110636          0   8110636   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/nvme0n1p2    1998672     213284   1664148  12% /boot
/dev/nvme0n1p1     523248       8020    515228   2% /boot/efi
/dev/loop1          56832      56832         0 100% /snap/core18/2066
/dev/loop0          56832      56832         0 100% /snap/core18/1944
/dev/loop2          71680      71680         0 100% /snap/lxd/19188
/dev/sda1      5813265944 5470772680  49450884 100% /home
/dev/loop3          69248      69248         0 100% /snap/lxd/20326
/dev/loop4          31872      31872         0 100% /snap/snapd/10707
/dev/loop5          32896      32896         0 100% /snap/snapd/11841
tmpfs             1622124          0   1622124   0% /run/user/1000
```

in /home I have an empty "lost+found" directory. Can I delete this one? Do you see something wrong on df's output?

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: I just don't want it on my /home, but with the rest of the system on /

Comment: It's there because it is a separate partition, don't bother with it, you may delete this folder but it will be recreated if needed.

Comment: Please treat it as a "system" directory and do not delete it. You can google about it, if you need more information. In general, it is not advised to manually manipulate files and folders owned by `root`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `/home` is mounted on a separate filesystem (partition). Every ext2, ext3 or ext4 filesystem (I don't know for others) has a `lost+found` subdirectory under the top directory of the filesystem. It is a system directory and it must be there. In case of filesystem errors, this directory is used by `fsck` to place recovered files there.